# How to create view for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Perhaps it will be an simple question but, I don't know how to achieve it simply.
I have two tables mentioned below.

**TableA**

```
ID  Student1 Student2 Student1_Class Student2_Class
1    S0001   S0002      A              A
2    S0001   S0003      B              A
```

**TableB**

```
  Class StudentID StudentName
    A     S0001     Jack
    A     S0002     Adam
    A     S0003     Lily
    B     S0001     Simpson
```

I'm expecting to get a result something like

```
   ID  Student1  Name1  Student2  Name2  Student1_Class Student2_Class
    1    S0001   Jack    S0002   Adam      A              A
    2    S0001   Simpson S0003   Lily      B              A
```

How can I create a view based on these two tables to get the desired result?

Comment: Your data is wrong: to get Simpson in the output then Student1_Class needs to be B for ID = 2.

Comment: @gbn, Thanks. Now it has been corrected.

Comment: still wrong: there is no A/S0003 match to get Lily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to JOIN on both Class and STudent becuase S0001 is repeated.

However, your output is wrong because there is no A/S0001 match for ID = 2 in TableA to get "Simpson". So assuming this is a typo, here you g0

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
 SELECT
   A.ID,
   A.Student1,
   B1.StudentName as Name1,
   A.Student2,
   B2.StudentName as Name2,
   A.Student1_Class,
   A.Student2_Class
 from
   TableA as A
   INNER JOIN
   TableB as B1 ON A.Student1_Class = B1.Class AND A.StudentID = B1.Student2
   INNER JOIN 
   TableB as B2 ON A.Student2_Class = B2.Class AND A.StudentID = B2.Student1
```

Comment: Yes, I think `g0` *is* a typo. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to join on `TableB` twice, once for each student

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
 SELECT
   A.ID,
   A.Student1,
   B1.StudentName as Name1,
   A.Student2,
   B2.StudentName as Name2,
   B1.Class as Student1_Class,
   B2.Class as Student2_Class
 from
   TableA as A
   INNER JOIN TableB as B1 on B1.StudentID = A.Student1 and B1.Class = TableA.Student1_Class
   INNER JOIN TableB as B2 on B2.StudentID = A.Student2 and B2.Class = TableA.Student2_Class
```

Comment: -1 on 3 counts 1. You'll get a partial Cartesian product because of S0001 2. The data in the question is wrong anyway 3. There are 2 upvotes and it's wrong